# Packages held back libnma-common (16.04 LTS)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

certain packages are being held up at sudo apt upgrade, namely **libnma-common** realted to mobile and wireless dialogues.

[image]

Investigating further at **sudo aptitude** reveals dependency problems, however, not the problem itself:

[image]

Is it safe to upgrade in aptitude?
Any experiences?

Thanks

Comment: Try *sudo apt full-upgrade*